# Find a string that contains 1 to 4 uppercase letters and 0 to 3 digits (visual studio code, javascript regex)

Tags: javascript, regex, visual-studio-code

From lines in a file i would like to find those that

- the lines starts with a year YYYY `^(202\d)` for example `2022`or `2023`
- followed by at least 1 and up to 4 uppercase letters ABCD `[A-Z]{1,4}` or up to 3 numbers `\d{1,3}` and at least one letter `[A-Z]{1}` for example `ABCD` or  `A123` or `1A23` or `123A`
- followed by either `A` or `R`

Examples

```
YYYYxxxxA   // find rows that match 2022xxxxA
2022A150A   // relevant matches
2022B260A   //     "
20223A70A   //     "
20224B84A   //     "
20224B  A   // not relevant due to spaces \s\s 
20221234A   // not relevant due to 4 digits and no letter
```

In [visual-studio-code](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code) i tested [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) (see [my demo@regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/T9VgsF/2))

These two  regex seem to work

```
2022(\d\D\w\w|\D\d\w\w|\d\d\D\w|\d\d\w\D|\D\D\D\D)A
// or
^(202\d)(\d{0,3}[A-Z]{1,4}|[A-Z]{1,4}\d{1,3})([\dA-Z]{0,4})A
```

#### Explanation from regex101.com

- at start of a line
- 1st Capturing Group (202\d) matches `202` literally and `\d` matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
- 2nd Capturing Group (\d{0,3}[A-Z]{1,4}|[A-Z]{1,4}\d{1,3})
- 2 Group 1st Alternative `\d` matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9]){0,3} matches the previous token between 0 and 3 times
- 2 Group 1st Alternative  match a single character present in the list below [A-Z]
  {1,4} matches the previous token between 1 and 4 times
- the other alternatives `|` are a variation of the first

[image: Demo at regex101.com]

#### Question

I would like to know if there is a better option than

```
^(202\d)(\d{0,3}[A-Z]{1,4}|[A-Z]{1,4}\d{1,3})([\dA-Z]{0,4})A
```

for `(xxxx)` should contain at least 1 uppercase and no more than 3 digits?

Test with [my demo](https://regex101.com/r/T9VgsF/2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your final regex will also match the below two lines, because it allows up to 3+4+4 characters for that second part, and also just 1 letter:

```
2022999BBBB9999A
2022BA
```

For the part that must have 4 alphanumericals, including at least one letter, you could express that condition as follows:

- match exactly four characters that are either digits or uppercase letters
- require that one of those must be an uppercase letter, using look-ahead

Like this:

[`^(202\d)(?=.{0,3}[A-Z])([\dA-Z]{4})A`](https://regex101.com/r/llGKia/2)

Comment: I do not quite get it:  `(?=.{0,3}[A-Z])`  uses the [Lookahead assertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#other_assertions): `x(?=y)` This `matches x only if "x" is followed by "y" `. But `y` is not part of the match result. How does this help for `([\dA-Z]{4})` which matches everything that starts with a digit `1B23` or `9999` but not `A123`?

Comment: Look ahead does not need anything to precede it like in `x(?=y)`. It makes the engine look forward and independent on whether that look ahead is successful or not, it does not "eat" any characters. It stays where it is. If the look ahead fails, it backtracks. If it succeeds it continues. That continuation then tries to match `([\dA-Z]{4})` which is the only part that actually "consumes" characters.

Comment: Is my understanding of `(.{0,3}[A-Z])`  correct? In `B234` Only "B" matches due to 0x any character followed by 1 letter. And "B1" is no match because 1x any character is followed by a digit  (a none-letter). See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/QVQsfz/1)

Comment: The pattern `(.{0,3}[A-Z])` will never look past that "B" in "B1", but still matches the "B". So it will match "B", "9B", "99B" and "999B", and will not judge what follows after that.